# laravel publish dependancy packages assets

Tags: php, laravel, package

I am just starting to learn about laravel packages, and started my first package.

My package requires some other packages installed in the vendor directory of my package via composer. When I come to do assets:publish my package, I need it to also assets:publish the vendor packages as well.

How do I go about automating this, or is it just a matter of guiding the user through publishing each package separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can in Laravel call artisan inside of your application or package:

```
Artisan::call('assets:publish', array('--package' => 'Vendor/PackageName'));
```